# Why is RenderUI sometimes not updating?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I'm trying to develop the following Shiny user interface:

1. There's a number of possible graphs that can be displayed.
2. The newest graph is tied to various controls that can be tweaked.
3. When the user presses a button, the current state of the controls are saved and a new graph added, with the new graph then being "active". The old graph continues to use the saved state of the controls.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
ui = fluidPage(
  actionButton("add", "Add a graph"),
  sliderInput("obs", "Number of observations:",
    min = 0, max = 1000, value = 500
  ),
   uiOutput("box1"),
   uiOutput("box2"),
   uiOutput("box3")
      
)


server = function(input, output, session) {
    graphtable <- reactiveValues(i=1, data=NULL)
    icur <- reactiveVal(1)  

    observeEvent(input$add, {
                 graphtable$data <- rbind(graphtable$data, c(graphtable$i, input$obs))
                 icur(icur()+1)
    })

    output$box1 =renderUI({
        if (icur() == 1){
            tagList("Plot 1", actionLink("del1", "Delete"),plotOutput("activeplot")) 
        }else if (icur() > 1){
            tagList("Plot 1", actionLink("del1", "Delete"),plotOutput("plot1")) 
        }
    })
    output$box2 =renderUI({
        if (icur() == 2){
            tagList("Plot 2", actionLink("del2", "Delete"),plotOutput("activeplot")) 
        }else if (icur() > 2){
            tagList("Plot 2", actionLink("del2", "Delete"),plotOutput("plot2")) 
        }
    })
    output$box3 =renderUI({
        if (icur() == 3){
            tagList("Plot 3", actionLink("del3", "Delete"),plotOutput("activeplot")) 
        }else if (icur() > 3) {
            tagList("Plot 3", actionLink("del3", "Delete"),plotOutput("plot3")) 
        }
    })
    observeEvent(input$del1, {
                 icur(icur()-1)
                 graphtable$data = graphtable$data[-1,, drop=F]
    })
    observeEvent(input$del2, {
                 icur(icur()-1)
                 graphtable$data = graphtable$data[-2,, drop=F]
    })
    observeEvent(input$del3, {
                 icur(icur()-1)
                 graphtable$data = graphtable$data[-3,, drop=F]
    })
    output$plot1 = renderPlot({plot(1:graphtable$data[1,2])})
    output$plot2 = renderPlot({plot(1:graphtable$data[2,2])})
    output$plot3 = renderPlot({plot(1:graphtable$data[3,2])})
    output$activeplot = renderPlot({plot(1:input$obs, xlab = icur())})
}
```

Mysteriously, this code works... some of the time. The behaviour is fine when there's 1 or 2 graphs. But when you click to add a third graph, the RenderUI doesn't fully update. The text appears, but the active graph continues to be the 2nd graph!

Is there something I'm misunderstanding? How do I fix this? I have tried adding a delay with shinyjs to no avail but maybe I'm doing it wrong. Is there some way to force renderUI to update?

Comment: The problem is how `icur` is being nested within the reactive contexts.  (you're probably leaking memory too)  By your 3rd plot,  shiny needs to update 3 boxes and a chart for one of the boxes every time `icur` changes.  Shiny is executing the `output$activeplot` before the `plotOutput("activeplot")` is set at box 3. So there is nowhere for the plot to render.

Comment: Is that a problem though? Icur only changes once per click of the add plot button. And also the issue isn't that the activeplot isn't rendering at all - it's rendering in the wrong box...

Comment: The trick with shiny is having a clear reactivity graph. You don't have that. You have `icur` triggering nearly everything, **including elements within other elements**.   For example you could have icur trigger the creation of the graph and the graphs creation trigger the subsequent creation of the box.

Comment: No. I don't think this is correct. I changed the code so all of the renderPlots never change and just plot(1:10), and the problem still recurs. The problem is the race condition as described in my answer. It is fine for one input to change multiple elements of a shiny app.

Comment: Having icur trigger multiple events alone is fine; the problem is the part in bold. The race you describe is due to this.  See [here](https://mastering-shiny.org/reactive-graph.html)

Comment: I already explained that the race condition happens even if there's no elements within other elements that are reactive. Further, triggering one of the renderPlots does not actually trigger the renderUI it's accessed by.

Comment: Try this code that strips out reactive elements from the plots. However simple you make the reactivity graph, it still fails. https://pastebin.com/A6V0yJwH

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't think I can help you. That code seems nonsensical to me. You say yourself that you don't even know if the `isolate`s do anything.  Thats not a good sign. We're not discussing shiny the same way. Good luck with you application.

Comment: Fine, but I'm satisfied that you are completely wrong about this. The link you gave is useful though, since it gives the point I raised - that shiny essentially executes outputs at random (14.3.1). That's the underlying issue.

Comment: Great. Keep reading. It gets better. `reactlog` is a good package. May help you see how wrong i am.

Answer (score 1):

With some fiddling I might have identified the issue - it seems like there's a race condition where when icur updates, potentially box3 could update before box2 does (reactive expressions apparently do NOT execute in the order they appear in the code). This creates a problem in that box2 is still showing activeplot, so box3 is unable to show the graph it wants to be showing. Indeed there's a javascript error to that effect. I don't really understand why this means box2 would continue to show activeplot though. Perhaps because of the aforementioned error it also stops trying to update box2 as well.

Well, the below code seems to work: (I also added in some isolates, but I don't know if they are required)

```
ui = fluidPage(
  actionButton("add", "Add a graph"),
sliderInput("obs", "Number of observations:",
    min = 0, max = 1000, value = 500
  ),
   uiOutput("box1"),
   uiOutput("box2"),
   uiOutput("box3"),
   uiOutput("box4"),
   uiOutput("box5")
      
      
      )


server = function(input, output, session) {
    graphtable <- reactiveValues(i=1, data=NULL)
    icur <- reactiveVal(1)  

    observeEvent(input$add, {
                 graphtable$data <- rbind(graphtable$data, c(graphtable$i, input$obs))
                 icur(icur()+1)
                 icur()
    })

    output$box1 =renderUI({
        if (icur() == 1){
            tagList("Plot 1", actionLink("del1", "Delete"),plotOutput("activeplot")) 
        }else if (icur() > 1){
            tagList("Plot 1", actionLink("del1", "Delete"),plotOutput("plot1")) 
        }
    })
    output$box2 =renderUI({
        if (icur() == 2){
            tagList("Plot 2", actionLink("del2", "Delete"),plotOutput("activeplot1")) 
        }else if (icur() > 2){
            tagList("Plot 2", actionLink("del2", "Delete"),plotOutput("plot2")) 
        }
    })
    output$box3 =renderUI({
        if (icur() == 3){
            tagList("Plot 3", actionLink("del3", "Delete"),plotOutput("activeplot")) 
        }else if (icur() > 3) {
            tagList("Plot 3", actionLink("del3", "Delete"),plotOutput("plot3")) 
        }
    })
    output$box4 =renderUI({
        if (icur() == 4){
            tagList("Plot 4", actionLink("del4", "Delete"),plotOutput("activeplot1")) 
        }else if (icur() > 4) {
            tagList("Plot 4", actionLink("del4", "Delete"),plotOutput("plot4")) 
        }
    })
    output$box5 =renderUI({
        if (icur() == 5){
            tagList("Plot 5", actionLink("del5", "Delete"),plotOutput("activeplot")) 
        }else if (icur() > 5) {
            tagList("Plot 5", actionLink("del5", "Delete"),plotOutput("plot5")) 
        }
    })
    observeEvent(input$del1, {
                 graphtable$data = graphtable$data[-1,, drop=F]
                 icur(icur()-1)
    })
    observeEvent(input$del2, {
                 graphtable$data = graphtable$data[-2,, drop=F]
                 icur(icur()-1)
    })
    observeEvent(input$del3, {
                 graphtable$data = graphtable$data[-3,, drop=F]
                 icur(icur()-1)
    })
    observeEvent(input$del4, {
                 graphtable$data = graphtable$data[-4,, drop=F]
                 icur(icur()-1)
    })
    observeEvent(input$del5, {
                 graphtable$data = graphtable$data[-5,, drop=F]
                 icur(icur()-1)
    })
    output$plot1 = renderPlot({plot(1:isolate(graphtable$data)[1,2])})
    output$plot2 = renderPlot({plot(1:isolate(graphtable$data)[2,2])})
    output$plot3 = renderPlot({plot(1:isolate(graphtable$data)[3,2])})
    output$plot4 = renderPlot({plot(1:isolate(graphtable$data)[4,2])})
    output$plot5 = renderPlot({plot(1:isolate(graphtable$data)[5,2])})
    output$activeplot = renderPlot({if ( icur() %% 2) plot(1:input$obs, xlab = isolate(icur()))})
    output$activeplot1 = renderPlot({if ( (icur()+1) %% 2) plot(1:input$obs, xlab = isolate(icur()))})

}
```

The point is to have *two* activeplots so there's never the case that two boxes are trying to show the same activeplot at the same time.

Maybe this is an awful and hacky solution, and maybe my understanding is incorrect, so perhaps someone else can find a better way of resolving this problem.